# How to handle out of scope data in rasa?

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

Handling unexpected inputs from user for training rasa chatbot, FallbackPolicy can be used but donno how to do it. Rasa version is 1.10.11.

Answer (score 0):

For 1.x, you can write a custom Python function describing what you want to happen. You can see an example in the legacy docs [here](https://legacy-docs.rasa.com/docs/core/fallbacks/). The basic idea is:

1. you create a policy that triggers when the confidence (either how certain the assistant is that they know what the user is saying or how certain it is that it knows what to say next) is below a certain level
2. that triggers your python action to run (you'll need to make sure you have your action server up and running)

Rasa 2.0 handles fallback a little differently, you can see more details [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/fallback-handoff#fallbacks).